# Pass dynamic url to React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use react-router-dom version ^5.1.2 and try to pass dynamic property. My root component looks like this:

```
export const RegisterRoutes: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = ({
  match,
}: RouteComponentProps) => {
  const root = match.url;

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${root}/success`} component={RegisterSuccess} />
      <Route exact path={`${root}/success/email`} component={RegisterEmail} />
      <Route exact path={`${root}/confirmation/email/:code`} component={RegisterEmailConfirmation} />
      <Redirect to={root} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Here is a child RegisterEmailConfirmation component:

```
export const RegisterEmailConfirmation: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = ({ match }) => {

  console.log(match.params.code) // expected 'code' property from the url 

  return (
     <SomeContent />
    />
  );
```

I have an url from the BE with dynamic 'code' parameter, it looks like this: register/confirmation/email?code=fjds@dfF. How can I render RegisterEmailConfirmation component and read 'code' property inside? What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using function component you could use `useParams` hook in your component. See from [`useParams`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) documentation:

> `useParams` returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters. Use it to access `match.params` of the current `<Route>`.

Try as:

```
export const RegisterEmailConfirmation: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = () => {
  let { code } = useParams();

  console.log(code);

  return <>
     { /* your implementation */ }
  </>
}
```

Also you can import as:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: seems, it does not recognize path 'localhost:3000/register/confirmation/email?code=fjds@dfF' and nothing renders

Comment: @s_kamianiok What happens if you use the URL as `register/confirmation/email/fjds@dfF`?

Comment: sorry, looks everything is okay. my mistake - I used email?code=fjds@dfF' instead of email/my-dynamic-code

Comment: @s_kamianiok Awesome, happy to help!